# Дефект в подсветке синтаксиса языка kotlin

Tags: дефект, подсветка-синтаксиса

Если в названиях переменных в котлине присутствуют цифры, то они выделяются как обычные:

```kotlin
val someval12345 = 6789
```

Здесь и 12345, и 6789 подсвечиваются одинаково, хотя 12345 выделяться не должно

Comment: С подсветкой сейчас вообще не очень.  См. [тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347738/682782/).  Вкратце, сайты сети *StackExchange* используют библиотеку, которая уже несколько лет не поддерживается, а недавно вообще была официально заброшена Гугелем.  Обсуждение альтернатив идёт не особо активно.

Comment: Обычные отступы выделяют нормально этот код, проверил. Так что как workaround можно так делать

Comment: @dIm0n А у меня не сработало. На основном сайте с тегом `kotlin` подсветка всегда одинаковая (отступы, `\`\`\``, `\`\`\`kotlin`). А на мете отступы и `\`\`\`` дают подсветку для какого-то дефолтного языка, независимо от тега.